# Switch default branch gets never reached, but needed for arbitrary return value/Exception

Tags: java, methods, enums, return, switch-statement

At the moment I am reading a Java book with lots of neat exercises. One of them wants me to implement modulo arithmetic for Mod-3 with an enum.

I reached a point where I have not clue how to implement a method in a way I could confidentially show it to someone else.

The method gets a natural number (incl. 0) and converts it to a modulo-3 value, returning it as an enum-element. My problem is the switch statement. As I do modulo-3 arithmetic and checked the preconditions I have exactly 3 possible cases to check, 0, 1 or 2. Each returns its corresponding enum-element, but the compiler simply has no knowledge about that **and expects me to define a `default` branch with a return statement**.

I would think of it as bad code, if one would define `return null` in `default`, knowing that it will never get executed and makes no sense (to me) to return `null`. So throwing an exception instead would better (I think), but now **I have to choose an exception type and will I need to define exception handling**, knowing that the logic makes a throw impossible (because of the `assert`s before)?

If you answer, please explain why your implementation is superior to the others. I deeply thank you for your time!

```
public enum Mod3 {
    Zero(0), One(1), Two(2);

    private final int value;

    Mod3(final int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a given natural number to a modulo value.
     * @param naturalNumber To be converted to modulo-value. Not negative.
     * @return The modulo-value of given naturalNumber. 0 <= value < 3.
     */
    Mod3 get(final int naturalNumber) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        final int moduloNumber;
        if (naturalNumber >= 0)
            moduloNumber = naturalNumber % 3;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument has not to be negative, but was " + naturalNumber);


        assert moduloNumber >= 0 && moduloNumber < 3: "moduloNumber should have been >= 0 and < 3, but was " + moduloNumber;
        switch (moduloNumber) {
            case 0: return Zero;
            case 1: return One;
            case 2: return Two;

            // I don't know what to do here.
            default: throw new WhatTypeOfExceptionToUseHere("Logic error! Should have never been thrown!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the compiler simply has no knowledge about that and expects me to define a default branch with a return statement

The compiler complains because your method **must** return something, and *sadly* the compiler is not *that smart* to understand you're just checking for 3 options.

Possible solutions (all of them includes removing the `default` case from the `switch`):

- Move the `throw new WhatTypeOfExceptionToUseHere` statement after the `switch`.
- Make your `0`, `1` or `2` case as the `default` instead (I don't really recommend doing this).
- Add a `return null;` after the `switch` statement.

For your `WhatTypeOfExceptionToUseHere`, you can define a new exception or use [`ArithmeticException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html). IMO it will be better the latter than the former.

Just to note, both [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) and `ArithmeticException` extend from [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), which mean they are [unchecked exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) and don't need to be specified in the method definition.

Comment: If I would throw an exception, would you define a new Exception class for that purpose or what type would you choose? And is returning `null` not bad code?

Comment: Good to know, that they extend from `RuntimeException`, I really have near to no experience. Nevertheless one of your recommendations is to return `null`, shouldn't I avoid that, because it may make no sense to someone reading my code, as null has no meaning here, as it is just meat for the compiler to keep quiet?

Comment: @th3m3s this depends on your programming style. As I pointed, they are just possible solutions, it will depend on the application designer to define which approach to use. IMO I would prefer to throw the `RuntimeException` and handle the exception in another layer in the app.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an idea to not assert first but make the default throw the error. This because assertions might be turned off by the JVM.

Comment: And if I remove the `assert` and throw an exception in the default branch, would you define your own Exception-class for that or would you choose a predefined one (if, which)? Additionally, would you handle the `Exception` somewhere or would you pass it to the JVM? Last, should the `assert` before the switch not be a good idea, because it really is an assertion to catch logic failure, because it is not possible, that the value differs from those checked by the assertion if the logic is correct, so it is just for development purposes and would not get activated in the build.

Comment: You should actually never us assertions to catch logic failure because assertions might be turned off. So there for your logic WILL fail. But if, ofc, it is only used for dev purposes it could be placed there. I would throw an IllegalArgumentException, but it's debatable..